# Cannot start docker service after fresh docker install

Tags: docker, iptables, systemctl, arch

**Problem**

I just installed `Docker` on my arch machine with

```
sudo pacman -S docker
```

Just after that I tried to initialize `Docker` services with

```
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

it is showing this error -

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xeu docker.service" for details.
```

it does not show any critical info about what the issue is, then as prompted I executed -

```
sudo systemctl status docker.service
```

it gives -

```
× docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-03-25 17:13:41 IST; 18min ago
TriggeredBy: × docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 24205 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 24205 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 112ms

Mar 25 17:13:41 workstation42 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Mar 25 17:13:41 workstation42 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 25 17:13:41 workstation42 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 25 17:13:41 workstation42 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 25 17:13:41 workstation42 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

and

```
journalctl -xeu docker.service
```

from that there was one warning prompt that I looked upon the web that stated -

```
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

apparently searching for online solutions I reached up to the point that either my `kernel` has to be upgraded or I have to upgrade `iptables` on my arch machine. It must not be an issue with `kernel` as just a few days back I installed lts version for arch in my machine, still I am new to arch it could be anything I updated the system and packages with `sudo pacman -Syu` before installing `Docker` and have updated the `iptables` package current version `iptables v1.8.9 (legacy)`

**Thanks**

I want to go deep down into the matter as what the issue really is as I keep getting problems every time I start system-wide services using `systemctl` for new packages that I install on my machine, maybe I am missing something or some configuration on my arch install.
I tried to keep it simple and clean thanks for your patients and kind help.